# Is there any comprehensive source for landing fee information?

Tags: usa, landing-fees

Is there any comprehensive source for landing fee information for US airports?

Airnav and the facility directory do not have landing fee information.

Also, going to airport web sites often is useless. For example, Massport lists landing fees for Hanscom on their web site, but do not list their fees for Logan.

Note that landing fees can be complicated. For example, there can be "landing fees" and "ramp fees" and others. So, usually the fee information is for a bunch of different stuff.

Comment: I'm not sure that there is, the problem is that landing fees/ramp fees are business information and set by the airport/FBO management. I doubt that the FAA (who publishes the Chart Supplement, the new name for AFD) would want to get involved in, just like fuel prices. Larger carriers may have negotiated fee structures with the airport as well. It would be nice if somebody consolidated the basic fees like they do for fuel though.

Comment: PFC (Passenger Facility Charge) fees [are published](https://www.faa.gov/airports/pfc/monthly_reports/) by the FAA, but these are separate from basic landing fees and tiedown fees. From the [FAA Airport Compliance Manual Order 5190.6B](https://www.faa.gov/airports/resources/publications/orders/compliance_5190_6/media/5190_6b_chap18.pdf), there is some guidance about how to determine landing fees. Not necessarily something the FAA is maintaining comprehensive data on.

Comment: The Airport/Facility Directory only states if there is a fee, not the amount. At military airports, the fees are fixed by law, but civilian airports have no such restriction. In other countries such as Germany the law states exactly how much is charged.

Comment: See "Resource Location" under what not to ask in [help].

Answer (score 0):

After working on the problem some more I have found there is not really any centralized source for landing fee information. Pretty much the only option is to call the FBO. However, you can get the FBO information from Flight Aware, assuming a US airport. For example, to get FBO information for Logan Airport in Boston, you would use the URL:

https://flightaware.com/resources/airport/KBOS

This tells you that the GA FBO for Logan is Signature and that their number is 617-561-2500. At that point you have to call them to find out more. For example, I did this and the answer was:

\$33 single engine piston landing fee
\$6 per hour parking
\$53.90 general landing fee
\$49.00 handling charge (waived if you buy at least 15 gallons of fuel)
 \$95 "security" charge
\$5 random bureaucracy charge

Comment: Is the fee actually called a "random bureaucracy charge" or is that something you made up?